# Code style settings in IntelliJ (indentation)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've imported a project from Eclipse into IntelliJ and I want to configure the code style settings. However I've encountered a problem when declaring Arrays.

The eclipse formatter formats the code as following:

```
@Before
public void prepareData() throws Exception //NOPMD
{
    LOG.info("Preparing setup data");
    new CoreBasicDataCreator().createEssentialData(null, null);
    CatalogManager.getInstance().createEssentialData(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, null);
    serviceLayerDataSetup.createJobPerformables();
    impExSystemSetup.createAutoImpexEssentialData(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Type.ESSENTIAL,
            CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
    cuppySystemSetup.importBasics(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS, new String[]
    { CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS_PLAYERS }), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
    cuppySystemSetup.importWC2002(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002, new String[]
    { CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_SETUP, CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_RESULTS_PRELIMINARIES,
            CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_RESULTS_FINALS, CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_BETS_PRELIMINARIES,
            CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_BETS_FINALS }), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));

    LOG.info("Finished preparation of setup data");

    LOG.info("Preparing session");
    JaloSession.getCurrentSession().setUser(UserManager.getInstance().getUserByLogin("sternthaler"));
    LOG.info("Finished preparation of session");
}
```

And IntelliJ reformats the code into:

```
@Before
public void prepareData() throws Exception //NOPMD
{
    LOG.info("Preparing setup data");
    new CoreBasicDataCreator().createEssentialData(null, null);
    CatalogManager.getInstance().createEssentialData(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, null);
    serviceLayerDataSetup.createJobPerformables();
    impExSystemSetup.createAutoImpexEssentialData(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Type.ESSENTIAL,
            CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
    cuppySystemSetup.importBasics(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS, new String[]
            { CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS_PLAYERS }), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
    cuppySystemSetup.importWC2002(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002, new String[]
            { CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_SETUP, CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_RESULTS_PRELIMINARIES,
                    CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_RESULTS_FINALS, CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_BETS_PRELIMINARIES,
                    CuppyConstants.PARAM_WC2002_BETS_FINALS }), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));

    LOG.info("Finished preparation of setup data");

    LOG.info("Preparing session");
    JaloSession.getCurrentSession().setUser(UserManager.getInstance().getUserByLogin("sternthaler"));
    LOG.info("Finished preparation of session");
}
```

If you are an IntelliJ user you can play with this code samples inside of their code style editor. 
Hope anyone of you guys can figure this out: )

Comment: Can you describe what is wrong with intellij formatting? It is good you put code here, but it would be better to describe it completely instead of a "Get the job done" question...

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to describe it. The only problem is with this new line Array identation (as seen from then example).

I cannot find the respective parameter in IntelliJ to set this

Answer (score 1):

You could use this plugin in Idea: [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546?pr=phpStorm)

Just search and install it in `Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories(button)`

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, but I do not think it answer's the OP ultimate question. He is looking to make a specific configuration in IDEA for code formatting. Your suggestion is good if an Eclipse formatting file is part of the project itself (in source control). But is not helpful if the no such file exists and the OP wants this type of formatting for all projects we works on in IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, You want this:

```
cuppySystemSetup.importBasics(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS, new String[]
    {CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS_PLAYERS}), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
```

to format like this

```
cuppySystemSetup.importBasics(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS, new String[]
{CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS_PLAYERS}), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
```

To do that, you need to set *Settings > Code Style > Java > Tabs and Indents > "Continuation indent"* to 0. Note however, that will make all wrapped lines flush. I'm not sure if that is what you desire. Or if you just want it for specific code. If so, can you please clarify.

Also note that in IDEA 13 (currently in [beta/EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP)) you can use turn off formatting for sections of code via comments. (This feature was added via [IDEA-56995](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56995)). The tags are configurable, and default to the values shown below

```
// @formatter:off
cuppySystemSetup.importBasics(new SystemSetupContext(Collections.singletonMap(CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS, new String[]
{CuppyConstants.PARAM_BASICS_PLAYERS}), Type.NOTDEFINED, CuppyConstants.EXTENSIONNAME));
// @formatter:on
```

You can easily create a *surround with* Live Template to add those tags to a block of code.

Comment: Hi, the Continuation ident doesn't help since then all of those new lines would be on the same identation level. You see that they are idented on my showcase code.

Comment: So is it a case that you want the opening bracket of any array declaration, even when defined as a argument to a method call, on the next line and flush with the previous line? If so, that is not possible in IDEA . If the setting existed, it would be in _Java > Wrapping and Braces > Array Initializer_. I recommend you open a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). _Sometimes_ code style requests are implemented pretty quickly. It all depends what [Denis](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/people/denis.zhdanov) (developer that works on the code style component) has on his plate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just use "keep when reformatting" "line breaks" in code style java.

Not really pretty, but it is sometimes the only way to deal with bad legacy code (with spaces and all...).

In your example, you can extract the declarations of arrays (and other variables) from your method calls, that way maybe you'll get the same result as Eclipse. Also, IMHO it could make your code easier to read as actually it is difficult to figure out quickly what this code is doing.

Comment: Hi, well the code itself doesn't really matter. Its just a copy/paste from an internal test from the platform itself : )

I'll try that out what you've written and come back to you